# this method must return a result of type Object

Tags: java, compiler-errors, linked-list

```
package LinkedList;

public class LinkedList {

public class Node {
    Object data;
    Node next;
    //Constructor of Node
    Node(Object data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    //getter
    Object getdata(){
        return this.data;
    }
    Node getnext(){
        return this.next;
    }
    //setter
    void setnext(Node n){
        this.next = n;
    }
}

Node header = null;
int size = 0;
//Constructor of LinkedList
public LinkedList(){};
//return size
int size(){
    return size;
}
//return that list is empty or not
boolean isEmpty(){
    if (size != 0){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
Object first(){
    return header.getdata();
}
Object Last(int size){
    Node c;
    for(int i=0 ;i<size-1 ;i++){
        c = header.getnext();
        if (i == size-2){
            Object returndata = c.getdata();
            return returndata;
        }
    }
}

}
```

`first()` Function doesn't have any error on eclipse.
but in `last()` Function, I get error that is this method must return  a result of type Object. How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Last() doesn't always return a value, even though it claims to. Every code path must result in a return.

```
Object Last(int size){
    Node c;
    for(int i=0 ;i<size-1 ;i++){
        c = header.getnext();
        if (i == size-2){
            Object returndata = c.getdata();
            return returndata;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have a return statement also outside the `for` loop. The one you have Will only run if loop is executed and conditions are met.

If there's nothing to return beyond the loop, add `return null;` as last statement.